# Find top most instance of same class, within an array or elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on simple click to reveal dropdown menu system that goes 2 levels deep and have run into a probably simple issue:

I want to close any open top level menu when another one is opened.

I have a super simple reduced case here: http://jsfiddle.net/gaberino/z8AZR/2/ with no open close behavior, just border colors/bold text for active states.

Basically I want to remove the .active class from any top level item when another top level item is clicked, but not affect 2nd level items. And I'd like to keep it all in the same click function that controls the rest of the menu.

the simple toggle script is here. See the fiddle for the HTML. That's OK. right? It's a bunch or nested list items and indenting that to get formatted properly here is a pain.

jQuery:

```
$('.handle').on("click", function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $panel = $this.next('.panel');
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.toggleClass('active');
    $panel.toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
        <ul class="panel">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul class="panel">
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>#
                <a href="" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
        <ul class="panel">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
        <ul class="panel">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
        <ul class="panel">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="handle">handle</a>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which class is what... `.handle` is the dropdown? `.panel` is the dropdown..? what is what?

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle? `.handle` is the toggle, `.panel` is the drop down. I guess I do need to put the HTML in here...I wish you could just fence code in ``` above and below like Github instead of the annoying indents.

Comment: HTML added to the question. Figured out I could do the indenting BS easily in ST and then paste in here. duh